# Unable to import xcframework in Swift Package

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I have created my xcframework called `MathFramework` which works fine when I load it directly to `.xcodeproj`, but then I created a Package project called `Mathable` and I am not able to import it in any file using `import MathFramework` as I can do in `.xcodeproj`. I have added xcframework in Package project by drag-and-dropping it inside `Frameworks` folder and putting it as a `binaryTarget` in `Package.swift` file.

If I try to import it, Xcode says: `No such module 'MathFramework'`.

This is how my Package project structure looks like:

[image]

And this is `Package.swift` file:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Mathable",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Mathable",
            targets: ["Mathable"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Mathable",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MathableTests",
            dependencies: ["Mathable"]),
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "MathFramework",
            path: "./Frameworks/MathFramework.xcframework"),
    ]
)
```

Is this a bug or is it up to me? I can't see what's wrong here.

What's worse, after I upload the package to Github and install it in another project, I can't use the methods from .xcframework(which should be included in package) after I import the `Mathable` package.

Answer (score 0):

Try to archive your xcframework and then add path to that archive: your final `Package.swift` should look like that:

```swift
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Mathable",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Mathable",
            targets: ["Mathable"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Mathable",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MathableTests",
            dependencies: ["Mathable"]),
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "MathFramework",
            path: "Frameworks/MathFramework.xcframework.zip"),
    ]
)
```

Comment: thanks, but still getting the same error. Btw, you forgot `./` before `Frameworks`

Comment: What kind of errors? 
`./` isn't mandatory, as search runs in package folder by default.